# Cannot get value of selection class (arselmenu)

Tags: javascript, python, drop-down-menu, selection

I'm a Python newbie. I'm trying to make a py script to select a value from dropdown list. I tried to find a guideline on Youtube. But they only instruct how to get data from "option value=...". My trouble is there is no "option value=..." on the selection class that I'm try to get. Methods I tried and didn't work:

selectionbox.select_by_visible_text('Resolved')

find_element_by_xpath("....").click()

Their value are in arselmenu like below:  (New/Assigned/In Progress/etc.)

```html
<div class="selection" style="top:0px; left:117px; width:174px; height:21px;" arselmenu="[{v:&quot;New&quot;},{v:&quot;Assigned&quot;},{v:&quot;In Progress&quot;},{v:&quot;Pending&quot;},{v:&quot;Resolved&quot;},{v:&quot;Closed&quot;},{v:&quot;Cancelled&quot;}]">
<input id="arid_WIN_3_7" type="text" class="text " readonly="" style="top:0px; left:0px; width:153px; height:21px;" title="Pending">
<a href="javascript:" class="btn btn3d selectionbtn" style="top:0px; left:153px; width:21px; height:21px;">
<img class="btnimg" src="../../../../resources/images/mt_sprites.gif" alt="">
</a>
</div>
```

Highly appreciate any advice. Best wishes.

---

*** Update:
Hi @Endothermic, I tried using Javascript as your suggestion and got the code below:

```html
Status_javaScript = "document.getElementById('arid_WIN_3_7').value='Resolved'"  #Status - Resolved

driver.execute_script(Status_javaScript)
```

But it does not take effect when I click Save. I mean it does not change the value from "Pending" to "Resolved". It display like I changed the value but it's not. Any suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: You need to use something like Selenium WebDriver to emulate a browser from Python.

Comment: I think you're confusing some things up a bit. On the browser (at least when in default), you can only use HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. To do what you want, you would need to use javascript. You can test your code using your browser's console and copying and pasting code you want to try out.

Comment: Hi @Bamar, I knew about Selenium WebDriver and sendkeys to textboxes successfully. Then I was stuck at selection boxes.

Comment: Hi @Endothermic, sorry for my bad knowledge. But I don't know anything Javascript or how to test by using browser's console. Python is easy to use, I think, so I started learning it to automate my stuffs. I will be thankful if you could suggest some Javascript video tutorials. Thank your for your time

Comment: Your javascript code is correct and should work. This seems to be a bug on the python side. While I am not sure what your final goal is, I would recommend looking into [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) and basic javascript, as it seems that you want to create a 'custom' autofill for a certain webpage.

Comment: If you are in Chrome, open the console, go to literally any web page (even a new tab would work), and press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`J`. Then, you can copy and paste javascript there to test it. You can try typing in `1+1` and pressing enter, and you should be able to see the answer `2`. You can also execute other code, but in general, to print a value, you would use `console.log("Hello World!")`.

Comment: To see the DOM where all the elements of the web page is at, click the `Elements` tab at the top of the console. You can also use `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`I` to get there directly if you do not already have the console open. Here you can see all the elements and subelements, including `div`, `input`, `p`, and more. Use the dropdown button next to any element to see the elements 'under' it.

Comment: Finally, you can also inspect an element directly. Over the element you want to inspect, right-click and choose `Inspect`. To learn javascript itself, you can use resources such as [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) and [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/) - though a google search will probably be your best friend.

Comment: Wow, Endothermic, what a detailed instruction! Good news is I tried to figured it out by mixing JavaScript and Python (I'm newbie to there 2 languages). Instead of give the textbox a value (which I figured out they set "if" rule behind), I send a click to its button by Javascript then locate the value in dropdown by XPath and send 1 more click by Python

Comment: Status_javaScript = "document.querySelector('#WIN_3_7 > div > a').click()" #locate Status button
driver.execute_script(Status_javaScript)

----


Status_select = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[1]') #locate Resolved
Status_select.click()

Comment: I apppreciate your suggestion about TamperMonkey. I didn't think about it before.